# Read single lines using FatFS on STM32

Tags: stm32, sd-card, fatfs

is there a clean way to read single rows with the FatFS Library on a STM32?

I need a function that fills a buffer with a specific row/line from a txt file on SD Card.

At the moment I read the file wiht f_read but I never know how long one row is:

```
f_read(&file.file_p, buffer, len, &bw);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's the `f_gets` function that lets you read the file line-by-line, but keep in mind that also in this case you need to have the buffer that is large enough to store largest possible line.

Link to documentation: http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/doc/gets.html

Comment: And how do i select the line with f_gets? Like when I want to read line 54

Comment: You don't. If you need such feature, you read the file line-by-line and count. I'm not aware of any file API (even on PC) that would allow you to do that. That would require keeping offsets within the file where each line starts, so that you can "jump" to them directly.

Comment: @JacekŚlimok, yeah this is C (or C++) you are going to need to do much manual stuff to do that. However, just implement it and chuck it into a function and now you can do it easily